# How to test if a method retrieves data in Jasmine + Angular14

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

As part of my job, I am working on an Angular project using v14, but im pretty new with unit testing with Jasmine.

My problem is that I need to test if a custom autocomplete component (which we created and is working as it should) is retrieving a list of objects that it requires, and i can't figure it out how to do it.

I will provide all my code and then what I've tried.

**component.ts:**

```
getFooList(): void {
    this.optionsFoo =
      this.foobar?.map((bar) => {
        return {
          label: bar.property ?? '',
          value: bar
        }
      }) ?? []
    this.optionsFooToDisplay = this.optionsFoo 
  }
```

The `optionsFooToDisplay` variable is an array of objects which look like this:

```
Option<FOO>[]
```

**Option interface:**

```
export interface Option<T> {
  label: string
  value: T
}
```

**FOO interface:**

```
export interface FOO {
  foo1?: string
  foo2?: string
  foo3?: string
  foo4?: string
  foo5?: string
  foo6?: string
}
```

And this is what I've tried so far:
**component.spec.ts**:

```
it('should retrieve list of foos', () => {
    const mockFoo: Option<FOO> =
      [
        {
          label: 'foooo',
          value: {
            foo1: '69420',
            foo2: 'baaaar',
            foo3: 'AA',
            foo4: 'BBBBB',
            foo5: 'CC',
            foo6: 'DDDDDD'
          }
        }
      ] ?? []
    expect(component.optionsFooToDisplay).toContain(mockFoo)
  })
```

And finally, this is the error that VSCode shows:

```
Type '{ label: string; value: { foo1: string; foo2: string; foo3: string; foo4: string; foo5: string; foo6: string; }; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Option<FOO>': label, value
```

I'm stuck there and I don't know how to develop that properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your issue has nothing to do with jasmine, it's a simple type error in this part of your spec:

```js
    const mockFoo: Option<FOO> =
      [
        {
          label: 'foooo',
          value: {
            foo1: '69420',
            foo2: 'baaaar',
            foo3: 'AA',
            foo4: 'BBBBB',
            foo5: 'CC',
            foo6: 'DDDDDD'
          }
        }
      ] ?? []
```

you're assigning an array to `mockFoo` but giving it the type `Option<FOO>`. you need to remove the enclosing brackets and just make it an regular Object. The following should work:

```js
it('should retrieve list of foos', () => {
    const mockFoo: Option<FOO> = {
          label: 'foooo',
          value: {
            foo1: '69420',
            foo2: 'baaaar',
            foo3: 'AA',
            foo4: 'BBBBB',
            foo5: 'CC',
            foo6: 'DDDDDD'
          }
        }

    expect(component.optionsFooToDisplay).toContain(mockFoo)
  })
```

`

Comment: Now it shows a different error, Argument of type 'Option<FOO>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Option<FOO>>

Comment: My bad, I missed that your were using `expect(...).toContain()` and not `toBe()` and fixed your type error the wrong way around. I edited my post to reflect this. You need to put the type as `Options<Foo>` but not assign an array to it (remove the enclosing brackets, basically this part: `[ ... ] ?? []`.

Then jasmine will check if the array `optionsFooToDisplay` contains your mock

Comment: Different error: Expected [  ] to contain Object( here is the object). So it seems that it expected the array to contain that object, but didnt, correct?

Comment: Now this is your test failing. It says that `component.optionsFooToDisplay` was an empty array when tested.

Comment: Yes, the error is that the test inst filling the array correctly, but idk why. Anyways, I upvote your answer because it should definitely work

Comment: Are you calling your `getFooList()` function from your test to update `optionsFooToDisplay` ?